# php sprintf does not return the exact value

Tags: php, printf

The php function sprintf does not return the exact value;

The sample code is as below:

```
<?php
$var1 = 10469116213008843;
echo $var1;
echo "\n";

$var2 = sprintf("%.0f", $var1);
echo $var2;
echo "\n";
?>
```

guess what will outcome?

on a 64bit os, it produce:

```
10469116213008843
10469116213008844
```

on a 32 bit os, it produce:

```
1.0469116213009E+16
10469116213008844
```

I am really confused, why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * 18456116213465313, 18456116950744489, 17705116944636053, 
 * 18456116950744489, 13368116212523055, 10469116213008843, 
 * 19986116955764391, 19591116945040018, 11882116944120195,
 * 19166116210920723, 19166116210920723 
 */
int main()
{
    double oddVariable = 18456116213465313;
    printf("%0.f\n", oddVariable);

    oddVariable = 18456116213465313;
    printf("%.0f\n", oddVariable);

    oddVariable = 18456116213465313;
    printf("%.0f\n", oddVariable);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: is is practical or theoretical question?

Comment: 10469116213008843 is too large to hold as an integer value, so it's being held as a float. Standard computer language warnings for float precision apply.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I met the problem in my project, and it ruined my whole weekend. after observed the runtime log, I haved figured out that it was all about sprintf function... it does not return the exact value...

Comment: may I ask, what real life entity produced an integer of such size?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, you are right, it is too large for a 32bit OS, but it should work well in 64bit os... unfortunately, this function return the wrong value

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel www.taobao.com it is their user picture category id. see more --> open.taobao.com   if you can read chinese

Comment: But you're explicitly forcing it to float (even on a 64-bit machine) using "%.0f"... try using "%d"

Comment: category id is not an integer, it is just a random string

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel  I agree that it is not an integer, but the CJSON treaded it as integer, i need to convert it back to string, it is why i use sprintf

Comment: WHAT? use sprintf with numeric placeholder to convert a string to a string?!

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you, I have just try you suggestion, it works on 64bit OS, but does not work on 32bit OS... the code is run on 64bit OS, I develop the code on my computer, a 32bit OS.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel taobao has provider a library to connect this site, but the library has a bug, as you can see, it return the category id as iteger.. I need to convert it to string.

Comment: so, you are using a NUMERIC placeholder for this. fantastic.

Comment: It won't work on 32-bit because the number is too large for 32-bit integer, so the float conversion is forced at that point... you can't really avoid it in 32-bit without enforcing string usage or bcmath.... but if it works for 64-bit it should solve your problem in production.,,, just makes it hard for you to develop

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel well, may be i should hack the library.  Thank you..

Comment: so, you want to say that this identifier gets broken before sprintf?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel No, the category id is what it is before sprintf, but after sprintf, it has been incremented by 1.. the sprintf broken thing..

Comment: so, why do you do sprintf at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some numbers are too large to be held in integers, so they are approximated using float mechanics. If you need to work with numbers of this magnitude untouched, consider using an extension like [BC Math](http://php.net/bc) or [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php). These extensions will allow you to perform operations on very large numbers and get their full string representation to output them.

Comment: … or [GMP](http://php.net/gmp) or [Math_BigInteger](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), depending on which PECLs are available.

Comment: and all three has absolutely nothing to do with the problem